# require NodeJS (NW.jS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Então gostaria de saber o seguinte, se eu trabalho com node js para criar sites eu posso criar exemplo: um arquivo CONEXAO.jS e depois dar o require dele em um outro arquivo para usar ele, até ai tudo certo.

Más estou desenvolvendo em nw.js. E tento criar a mesma coisa e dar o require mais e como se não existisse, esse jeito e possivel fazer no nw.js? se sim como por favor

Comment: Coloque o código de como está a fazer, e o erro que lhe aparece, e os locais onde estão os arquivos.

Comment: Olá coloquei a foto, está ai divido, do loado esquerdo está o meu modulo exportado e do direito require nele